# Error in my app in ruby on rails hosted in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Thaks for helping. 
I'm developing an app in ruby on rails hosted in heroku

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

This is what i get in heroku logs:

```
2014-11-16T00:34:45.183714+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-11-16T00:34:45.183727+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-11-16T00:34:45.183740+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-16T00:34:45.182107+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/home/search?q=todas+las+ganas+y+mi+entusiasmo&amp;entity_subtype=userpoint&amp;entity_type=object&amp;search_type=entities" for 188.165.15.198 at 2014-11-16 00:34:45 +0000
2014-11-16T00:34:45.183681+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-11-16T00:34:45.183694+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-11-16T00:34:45.183710+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-11-16T00:34:45.183723+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-11-16T00:34:45.183736+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-11-16T00:34:46.112900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-11-16T00:34:46.112917+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
```

I tryed migrating the db in heroku but i get this error:

Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... failed
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

```
Error:       connect timeout reached (Excon::Errors::Timeout)
Backtrace:   /Users/felipevelasquez/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.40.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:124:in `rescue in initialize'
             /Users/felipevelasquez/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.40.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:105:in `initialize'
             /Users/felipevelasquez/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.40.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:380:in `new'
             /Users/felipevelasquez/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.40.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:380:in `socket'
             /Users/felipevelasquez/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/excon-0.40.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:105:in `request_call'
```

I don't know how to identify the error in heroku. 
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try
`heroku run bundle`
to have your dependencies in place.

Comment: Done, but it doesn't work still having this result: We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information. I don't know how to investigate the error in my heroku logs.